# How to split a string by this string: |||

Tags: java

I'm parsing an HTML by jSoup and get the bellow output. the text is splitted by annotators into segments and marked each section by |||. So, I need to retrieve each segment.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtdEq.png)

```
File input = new File("C:\\Test\\aaa.html");
                Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8", "");
                Element body = doc.body();
                String body2 = body.toString();
                String[] test = body2.split("|||");
                for (String s:test)
                System.out.print(s+"111111111");
```

output:
11111111 111111111<111111111b111111111r111111111>111111111|111111111|111111111|111111111<111111111s111111111t111111111r111111111o111111111n111111111g111111111>111111111 111111111B111111111u111111111s111111111i111111111n111111111e111111111s111111111s111111111 111111111T111111111r111111111a111111111n111111111s111111111f111111111e111111111r111111111s111111111 111111111:111111111 111111111<111111111/111111111s111111111t111111111r111111111o111111111n111111111g111111111>111111111 111111111A111111111s111111111 111111111w111111111e111111111 111111111c111111111o111111111n111111111t111111111i111111111n111111111u111111111e111111111 111111111t111111111o111111111 111111111d111111111e111111111v111111111e111111111l111111111o111111111p111111111 111111111o111111111u111111111r111111111 111111111b111111111u111111111s111111111i111111111n111111111e111111111s111111111s111111111,111111111 111111111w111111111e111111111 111111111m111111111i111111111g111111111h111111111t111111111 111111111s111111111e111111111l111111111l111111111 111111111o111111111r111111111 111111111b111111111u111111111y111111111 111111111a111111111d111111111d111111111i111111111t111111111i111111111o111111111n111111111a111111111l111111111

Comment: please show us a code not a picture

Comment: or a link for your source/html snippet by pastebin

Comment: could you please paste the output you are getting here and what you have tried to split till now

Comment: @miny1997: links to external resources are discouraged, questions should be self-contained.

Comment: File input = new File("C:\\Test\\aaa.html");
     Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8", "");
     Element body = doc.body();
     String body2 = body.toString();
     String[] test = body2.split("|||");
     for (String s:test)
     System.out.print(s+"111111111");

Comment: @alitavakoli: please edit your question instead of posting this as a comment, it's hard to read code in here, as it's all jumbled together. Also don't forget to provide us with the actual and expected output of that code.

Comment: this is the output:111111111 111111111<111111111b111111111r111111111>111111111|111111111|111111111|111111111<111111111s111111111t111111111r111111111o111111111n111111111g111111111>111111111

Comment: please edit your post with the output and the code which you have shared in the comment section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am just guessing, but I think you are looking for something like this:

```
String s = "cheese|||bread";
String[] splits = s.split("\\|\\|\\|");
for (String split : splits) {
    System.out.println(split);
}
```

Output:

```
cheese
bread
```

---

Implemented in your code:

```
File input = new File("C:\\Test\\aaa.html");
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8", "");
Element body = doc.body();
String body2 = body.toString();
String[] test = body2.split("\\|\\|\\|");
for (String s:test)
   System.out.print(s+"111111111");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have text which has **|||** in it you can split it in a string array by the following regular expression

```
String text = "abc|||123|||#@&"
String[] splitarray = text.split("\\|\\|\\|); // using double slash so | is not interpreted as OR 
for(String s : splitarray)
  {
   System.out.println(s);
   }
```

output :

```
     abc
     123
     #@&
```